# Django REST framework - injecting views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Say I have a simple application with users, groups and users are members of the groups (a M2M relationship). So I create a viewset which shall do the following:

- `GET /group` lists all groups
- `GET /group/1` gives detail of a group
- `POST /group/1/member` adds a member specified in the request to group 1
- `GET /group/1/member` lists all members of group 1
- and some other CRUD operations on groups/memberships which are not relevant for my question.

To make the code as readable as possible, I came up with this solution:

```
class GroupViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    ...

    @action(detail=True, methods=["get", "post"])
    def member(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return MembershipView.as_view()(request, *args, **kwargs)


class MembershipView(ListCreateAPIView):
    # handle the membership somehow here
```

However, this approach ends with

```
The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `rest_framework.request.Request`.
```

Although manually instantiating a view inside another view and passing the request would most probably work in pure Django, the REST framework refuses to do this, as each DRF view expects a pure Django request and cannot just take an existing DRF request as it is.

I have two questions:

- Is my design idea bad? And if yes, how shall I redesign?
- Do you think it will be worth creating a pull request to DRF? Allowing this is very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think your URL structure may not really be conventionally RESTful. You should be using plurals to access your resources, i.e.

```
POST /groups/
```

returns groups.

```
POST /groups/1
```

fetches an item from the groups list with an id of 1. It makes things a little clearer.

Secondly, I personally would redesign your flow as I think the current design overcomplicates your REST structure.

Are Members and Groups distinct resources? I would say yes, these are distinct. So they should be kept in different endpoints. Have /members/ and /groups/ and use django's built in filters to get the desired behavior, i.e.:

```
GET /members/?group_id=1
```

This is cleaner and more RESTful. You are fetching members who have a corresponding group_id of 1.

If you really want to keep this embedded structure, You can probably do some magic with some of `rest_framework.decorators` `list_route` and `detail_route` to probably achieve your current desired behavior.

However, in my experience, I've found embedding like that causes issues with some django mechanics and makes for some gnarly URL routing. I really would advise keeping distinct endpionts.

You're basically doing this:

```
/list-view/detail-view/list-view/
```

I can understand use cases where this design could make sense on paper, but I don't think it's ideal.

Comment: and for creation of a new membership, i do just `POST /members/` and include in the data the id of the group?

Comment: Yes, that is how I would do it. HTTP actions taken on /members/  actions should correspond to the corresponding Member class in your backend. This keeps resource actions explicit and distinct. This is a design that is way easier to maintain in the long run.

Comment: Ok, I will think about this. And for my second question, do you think that DRF shall be capable of doing this? Do you believe it might sometimes come in handy or not at all?

Comment: I'm not sure. To be honest, I don't know if this violates REST best practices, but it may. I think it unnecessarily muddles the resource structure. What benefit does this structure have over current REST best practices? I don't see advantage. What if I wanted /list/detail/list/detail/list/?